# AngularJS: Using directive with $scope values on button to update model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to design for best practices in AngularJS, but I'm brand new. I currently have a $scope function which I would like to move to a directive. Should I?

I have a table that shows an overview of a DB table, which clicks open into a modal input form, with every field of the DB row. I want to be able to click a button and delete the row that is currently in focus from the table.

I've built REST APIs to handle a delete request, and I have a working remove() function in the modal's controller.

How can I/ SHOULD I move this to a directive?

Current working code: Controller

```
$scope.remove = function() {
    var request = {
        type : $scope.type,
        id : $scope.row.id
    }
    console.log(request);
    $.post("Remove", request).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (i = $scope.tableData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ($scope.tableData[i].id == $scope.row.id)
                $scope.tableData.splice(i, 1);
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }           
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

};
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="updateChanges" class="btn btn-danger"
    ng-click='remove()' data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
```

In my head, the button would have not have 'ng-click', but a 'delete-entry' attribute, which is a directive that accomplishes the same thing as remove() does now.

Comment: You need to move your function to service instead of directive. Don't confuse logic with view. Directive mostly used for view, services - for logic, controller connect them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that